# primes of the form $p=8k+1, 8k+3$ can be expressed as $p=a^2+2b^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have trouble showing that primes of the form $p=8k+1, 8k+3$ can be expressed as $p=a^2+2b^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried or thought about? Do you know the analogous statement for $p=a^2+b^2$?

Comment: I know that $p=a^2+b^2$ if $p=1\mod4$.

Comment: In case of $p=8k+1$, I tried that $a^2=-2b^2\mod p$, $(\frac{-2b^2}{p})=1$, so I get $pk=a^2+2b^2$, $0<k<p-1$. I hope to prove that $k$ should be $1$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that statement ($p=a^2+b^2$) (without Gaussian integers)? Your problem can be solved similarly.

Comment: I can prove it using pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Try the same method. What do you get?

Comment: In case of $p=1\mod8$, I think that I proved $p=2a^2+b^2$ using same method but I just used $(\frac{-2}{p})=1$. It means that $p=7\mod8$ also can be expressed as $p=2a^2+b^2$. Is it right? and how to prove if $p$ is a form of $8k+3$? I need your hint...

Comment: It is $3 \pmod{8}$, not $7\pmod{8}$. Since you only used the fact that $(\frac{-2}{p})=1$ (which holds for $p \equiv 1, 3 \pmod{8}$), there is no need to separate the $2$ cases. Also, if you want me to be notified of your comment, start your comment with @IvanLoh

Comment: @IvanLoh Isn't it that $(\frac{-2}{p})=1$ holds for $p\equiv 1,7\pmod{8}$?

Comment: @IvanLoh Oh, I mistake $\(\frac{-2}{p})$ for $(\frac{2}{p})$. Thanks. You are good adviser.

Comment: Since you have solved the problem, I suggest that you answer your own question.